# Не высвечивать последнюю строку запроса для изменяющейся длины таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql, dbeaver

Возникла необходимость написать sql-запрос, который собирал бы данные по всем платежам за всю имеющуюся историю в базе, агрегировал их по месяцам и выдавал таблицу без информации о последнем месяце (то есть выплевывал таблицу без последней строки). Знаю, что задать необходимое количество строк можно с помощью метода LIMIT, однако, из-за того, что длина таблицы каждый месяц увеличивается на 1 строку, задать константным значением не удается.
Можно ли как-то задать значение LIMIT через подзапрос? Или как-то еще?

Текст запроса оставляю ниже:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(TEXT(ПериодПлатежа), 1, 7) AS Месяц, sum(Сумма) AS Общая_сумма_платежей

FROM stage_uvz.jsonPayments

WHERE ПериодПлатежа > '2012-01-01' and Сумма > 0

GROUP BY Месяц

ORDER BY Месяц

LIMIT 120
```

Comment: так ограничьте дату не только снизу, но сверху.

Comment: ```LIMIT (select count(*) ....)``` или ```with (select @temp = (select count(*)...) as tmp_count..... LIMIT @tmp_count.temp``` еще оконной функцией можно проверить что запись последняя и не выводить ее, но на память не напишу такое :)

Comment: Убираешь свой запрос в подзапрос, вешаешь обратную сортировку (по убыванию года-месяца) и добавляешь `LIMIT 1, овердохрена`. А во внешнем запросе просто пересортировываешь по возрастанию года-месяца.

Comment: а зачем сначала заставлять базу агрегировать данные по последнему месяцу, а потом выкидывать этот результат? Может не выбирать данные за последний месяц просто?